# PyCharm просит ввести Interpreter options. Что это?

Tags: python, pycharm

Установил PyCharm, загрузил туда свои проекты. Решил запустить, а он говорит

> введите Interpreter options

Что туда надо ввести?!

Comment: Нужно установить питон: https://www.python.org/getit/

Answer (score 2):

PyCharm сам не имеет вставленный интерпретатор Питона.

Когда у вас пока нет отдельной инсталляции Питона, нужно это сделать.

Затем после нового спуска PyCharm он вероятно увидит эту инсталляцию Питона - когда нет, нужно его добавить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]