# Как корневой Python3.6.9 установить в PyCharm где стоит Python3.8.6

Tags: python, pycharm

У меня вот какой вопрос:Как корневой Python3.6.9 установить в PyCharm где стоит Python3.8.6? Никак не получается проложить путь. И ещё, учусь писать игры по роликам и почему то когда добавляю аудио файлы: mp3, wav, ogg, то в меню проекта они отображаются с вопросиками, т.е. не активированы. Как это исправить? И библиотека pyaudio и не только она не устанавливается в PyCharm,а в корневой Python3.8.6 устанавливается, поэтому и хочу проложить его путь к PyCharm.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "корневым Python"? Просто зайдите в Settings, в настройках проекта в Python Interpreter укажите нужный вам интерпретатор. И еще, не нужно задавать несколько вопросов в одном.

Comment: Вот тут есть скриншот окна настроек: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852797

Comment: у вас в проекте нет виртуального окружения? установите в него любую версию пайтона и любые нужные этому проекту библиотеки и пользуйтесь

Comment: Не получается, он его не видит.

Comment: Всё удалил и установил по новой пользуясь подсказками с этих сайтов::https://python-scripts.com/install-python-3-8-linux   https://tehnichka.pro/install-pycharm-linux/  всё заработало как надо, есть другая проблема, но спрошу в другом разделе.